# PostgreSQL: как вставить переменную в команду restart sequence?

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

Есть команда сброса последовательности к заданному числу

```
alter sequence id_sec restart with 100;
```

Как в ней использовать myBatis-переменную `#{value}`?

Пробовал конструкции, вроде:

```
alter sequence id_sec restart with quote_literal(#{value});
```

-- безрезультатно. PostgreSQL не хочет парсить никакие мои варианты переменных и работает, только если подставить число напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено, вместо restart sequence можно использовать

```
select setval('id_sec', #{value});
```